# Incorrect return values: C++

Tags: c++, floating-point

I am running a simple program to test out the limits of floats and integer calculations in C++. I understand that #15 and #19 are incorrect values that are being returned, but why is #15 specifically wrong? And I don't think #19 is being divided by 0 to return "inf" so why is it doing this?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

float hyp(float x, float y) {
    return sqrtf(x*x + y*y);
}

#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    float x = 3.0f, y = 4.0f, z = 5.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        float e = fabsf(hyp(x, y) - z) / z;
        printf("%2d %e\n", i, e);
        x *= 10.0f, y *= 10.0f, z *= 10.0f;
        std::cout << z << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
 0 0.000000e+00
50
 1 0.000000e+00
500
 2 0.000000e+00
5000
 3 0.000000e+00
50000
 4 0.000000e+00
500000
 5 0.000000e+00
5e+06
 6 0.000000e+00
5e+07
 7 0.000000e+00
5e+08
 8 0.000000e+00
5e+09
 9 0.000000e+00
5e+10
10 0.000000e+00
5e+11
11 0.000000e+00
5e+12
12 0.000000e+00
5e+13
13 0.000000e+00
5e+14
14 0.000000e+00
5e+15
15 1.073742e-07
5e+16
16 0.000000e+00
5e+17
17 0.000000e+00
5e+18
18 0.000000e+00
5e+19
19 inf
5e+20
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: The results you see depend on the implementation of `sqrtf`. It is hard to say anything beyond that. The x, y, and z values should be stored with full precision as the number of decimal digits that can be stored without rounding errors (the value of DECIMAL_DIG) in a float is `21` (on my machine at least).

Comment: Part of your confusion comes from assuming that dividing a nonzero number by zero is the only way to obtain inf. inf is the result of any operation the result of which cannot be represented by a finite number for being too large.

Comment: @madmann91 `DECIMAL_DIG` applies to the `long double` type. All floating-point types here are `float`. A C++ implementation may use `long double` precision for `float` intermediate results and constants, but C and C++ standards imply elsewhere that the contents of a `float` variable have to be a value representable as a `float`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Thank you for pointing that out. Under the reasonable assumption that the compiler uses IEEE 754 binary32 for float, the variables x, y, and z should nevertheless be stored with full precision for the values used here.

Answer (score 4):

The largest single precision floating point number is about `1.7e+38` (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32)). When you try to square `5e+19`, the result is `2.5e39`, which is too large, so you get `inf`.

The reason you're getting a non-zero result for #15 is because floating point is approximate. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)